# How to attach a non-child div to the bottom of another div

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently looking to move a div to attach to the bottom of another div that isn't wrapping it.

I'm using a Word Press theme called Divi, a wysiwyg editor, and the client wants the menu to be below another div that is in the actual Divi editor, while the menu is generated by a combination of HTML and PHP

```
<div id="top-header"<?php echo $et_top_info_defined ? '' : 'style="display: none;"'; ?>>
        <div class="container clearfix">

        <?php if ( $et_contact_info_defined ) : ?>

            <div id="et-info">
            <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_phone_number = et_get_option( 'phone_number' ) ) ) : ?>
                <span id="et-info-phone"><?php echo et_sanitize_html_input_text( $et_phone_number ); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_email = et_get_option( 'header_email' ) ) ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( 'mailto:' . $et_email ); ?>"><span id="et-info-email"><?php echo esc_html( $et_email ); ?></span></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php
            if ( true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
                get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );
            } ?>
            </div> <!-- #et-info -->

        <?php endif; // true === $et_contact_info_defined ?>

            <div id="et-secondary-menu">
            <?php
                if ( ! $et_contact_info_defined && true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
                    get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );
                } else if ( $et_contact_info_defined && true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
                    ob_start();

                    get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );

                    $duplicate_social_icons = ob_get_contents();

                    ob_end_clean();

                    printf(
                        '<div class="et_duplicate_social_icons">
                            %1$s
                        </div>',
                        $duplicate_social_icons
                    );
                }

                if ( '' !== $et_secondary_nav ) {
                    echo $et_secondary_nav;
                }

                et_show_cart_total();
            ?>
            </div> <!-- #et-secondary-menu -->

        </div> <!-- .container -->
    </div> <!-- #top-header -->
<?php endif; // true ==== $et_top_info_defined ?>
```

I've tried inserting the code above into a code module, as that would effectively be the simplest solution, but it turns out, it does not support PHP. :( If there is a secure way to enable php in content, this is another viable solution.

This is easily done with position: absolute and top: number, however, this is not responsive, and would require several media queries at odd breakpoints as the div it needs to respond to gets taller as content gets pushed down.

Luckily, the client wants it to overlap the div below its anchor div,so we don't need to account for the height of the div to push it further down.

I'd like to know if there is an easier way to do this that is cleaner than several media queries with different top values.

Ideally, the solution would be pure css.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had DIVI project recently that required a lot of  custom stuff  and  the best solution almost always was  to edit the php files in my child theme.

However if you need it inside the content it's better to make it on a shortcode.